# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Import failed: File accessed outside allowed roots

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, intellij-plugin

A junit test runs fine on my local OS X, but there would be an error about "allowed roots" in Jenkins. I've tried chmod -R 777 *, which did not help. Question: is there a flag I can pass to JUnit to explicitly specify allowed roots?

```
1) testExcludes1(com.twitter.intellij.pants.integration.OSSPantsScalaExamplesIntegrationTest)
                 junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Import failed: File accessed outside allowed roots: file:///export/hdb3/jenkins/workspace/intellij_plugin_ci_trigger@2/.cache/pants/pants;
                 Allowed roots: [/export/hdb3/jenkins/workspace/intellij_plugin_ci_trigger@2/.pants.d/intellij/plugins-sandbox/test, /tmp/unitTest_excludes1_569/testExcludes10, /var/lib/jenkins, /export/hdb3/jenkins/workspace/intellij_plugin_ci_trigger@2/.pants.d/resources/services, /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre, /tmp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a VirtualFile System access issue with IntelliJ. Answer found at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129297#